# What order to apply noise shaping and anti-aliasing to an idealized synth

Tags: quantization, anti-aliasing-filter, dithering

I am trying to write a small synth code that goes something like this,
I have an abstract symbolic sound representation, sine/square/saw waves. To generate final sound and make it sound good I thought of the following steps;

- At first oversample the abstract symbolic representation
- apply noise shaped dither
- apply anti-aliasing algorithm
- last. downsample to local devices sample rate or FLAC sample rate

Point is that the input is not going to be quantized, but more of a symbolic representation to allow arbitrary-precision oversampling. The way I think of it is something like an abstract representations of unit generators, which can run at arbitrary rate depending on the output selected.

In general, I am trying to minimize quantization errors and lower perceived noise within the context of working over symbolic sound, but only once I know the target sample rate.

I am confused about ordering of the middle 2 steps.
What order should noise shaped dither and anti-aliasing be applied? Is placing downsampling last the correct idea or should it maybe be reordered too?

Comment: Generally the order of operation would be 1) gnerate signals are oversampled rate, 2) lowpass filter and down-sample, 3) quantize, add dither and noise shape for file export. Note that you should ONLY quantize and dither for the final product (i.e. the studio master). If there will be any post processing (like import to a DAW) just leave it in floating point.

Comment: Thanks. For a more advance anti-aliasing filter; could lowpass just be replaced by it?

Comment: An anti-aliasing  IS a low-pass filter. It's required to minimize aliasing during the down-sampling process. What "more advanced" features would you add ?

Comment: Generating alias-suppressed classic analog waveforms is a whole topic in and of itself.

Comment: I don't know where the noise shaping and dithering is coming into the picture yet.  Can't you make your synthesis algorithm work in floating-point?  Dithering and noise-shaping is only needed when there is a word width reduction.  We call that "quantization".

Comment: If you're just trying to synthesize nice analog-like waveforms, you should look into wavetable synthesis.  It's pretty efficient and straight-forward.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I mean I have an idealized shape of the waveform, PCM can perfectly reproduce idealized shapes only for very few waveforms and even then for sine-like ones, only at rational multiples of sampling frequency if I understand correctly. That's where the dither and noise-shaping comes in to reduce the quantization error. The kind of synthesis I am doing is additive mostly.

Comment: @Hilmar I think when I meant more advanced I was confusing IIR/FIR lowpass filters and thinking of IIR as lowpass and FIR as more advanced one. I guess what I am asking is Does the characteristic of the lowpass filter affect the operation order?

Comment: This is not about dither and noise shaping.  This really is about [Wavetable Synthesis](https://blog.native-instruments.com/what-is-wavetable-synthesis/#sample-based-synthesis).  Now I have a [paper that's now essentially too old](https://www.academia.edu/55184604/Wavetable_synthesis_101_a_fundamental_perspective) but you're welcome to get it.

Comment: What you need to do is use a waveform look-up-table with enough samples (or points) in it so that you can linearly interpolate without any bad effects.  I suggest 4096 points (memory is cheap).  But you will need about two waveform tables for ***each*** octave.  One at C and another at F#.  Each octave.  The wavetables for higher pitch will have fewer harmonics at the higher end but the harmonics it keeps have exactly the same amplitude and phase as the lower-pitched wavetables.  Crossfade between adjacent pitched wavetables when your pitch is inbetween.

Comment: I can send you some C code for the lowest level synthesis.  But you will have to construct the code that goes around it.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Why is it not? I have an abstract waveform. I need to produce a wavetable that lowers the noise floor for this abstract waveform. I need to dither and noise shape the frequencies within this waveform to lower the noise once sampled or do I not?

Comment: Okay, you can oversample the waveform virtually perfectly, with almost no added quantization noise.  So what does adding dither to that result do for you?  It makes it noisier but it doesn't do anything to make your oversampled waveform any better.

Comment: Now applying the anti-aliasing algorithm is simply removing harmonics from your original sine/square/sawtooth.  Which harmonics you need to remove is a function of your sample rate and the pitch of the tone using that waveform.  Still all this can be done in floating-point or double-precision floating point.  There isn't any dithering or noise-shaping going on here.  ***Only*** when you take your `float` or `double` and cast that to an integer with fewer bits is when dithering and noise-shaping might be used.